# alert() triggers form submission

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to *eliminate the "enter event" default value* on `type=text`, which triggers submit on the form. I do so with the following:

```
var onEnter = function(values){
    $("#"+values['id']).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var function_to_call = window[values['function']];
            if(typeof function_to_call === 'function'){
                if(values['parameters']!= null){
                    parameters = values['parameters'];
                    var args;

                    if(typeof parameters === 'string')
                        args = parameters.split(',');
                    else
                        args = new Array(parameters);

                    function_to_call.apply(window, args);
                }
                else function_to_call();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

The code that matters for *taking away the default event* is

```
event.preventDefault();
return false;
```

The rest of code just calls a function with parameters or no parameters. The thing is, inside the functions called, there´s a condition that triggers an alert. Here´s the deal:

1. If **alert is not triggered**, `[enter]` does not trigger form submission
2. if **alert is triggered**, form submission is triggered

The function called on every `type=text` is the same, and here is the alert condition:

```
......
if(!regex_match(item)){
        alert("Solo son posibles los siguientes caracteres: '.' ',' 'a-z' 'a-Z' '0-9' y ' '");
        return;
 }
 .....

var regex_match = function(text){
    regex = /^[_., 0-9a-záéíóúñ]+$/i;
    return regex.test(text);
}
```

Things tried:

- "`return false;`" after `alert(...)`;

I am new to JavaScript, could anyone point out why this could be happening?

Comment: You say yourself that `return false` prevents form submission, but you don't have that with the alert. (`event.preventDefault()` should be enough, but from the question it's not clear if that's ever applied.)

Comment: Please start from the beginning and EXPLAIN what the aim of the whole thing is. If you use the form to ajax stuff, REMOVE the submit button and return false in the submit event. If not, tell us more

Comment: Also you want to change `event.preventDefault()` to `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly surprised by that (and expect you'll find the behavior varies from browser to browser), but `alert` is a funny beast somewhat at odds with the rest of the browser environment, so...

Since you always want to stop the default behavior, I'd recommend either:

1. Don't use `alert`, which is fairly ugly anyway (use any of the many "modal" dialog plug-ins for jQuery, or just do your own with a styled, absolutely-positioned `div`), or
2. Take the `alert` out of the event handling sequence, like this:

   ```
   var onEnter = function (values) {
       $("#" + values['id']).keydown(function (e) {
           if (e.which == 13) {
               setTimeout(finishHandling, 0);
               return false;
           }

           function finishHandling() {
               var function_to_call = window[values['function']];
               if (typeof function_to_call === 'function') {
                   if (values['parameters'] != null) {
                       parameters = values['parameters'];
                       var args;

                       if (typeof parameters === 'string')
                           args = parameters.split(',');
                       else
                           args = new Array(parameters);

                       function_to_call.apply(window, args);
                   } else function_to_call();
               }
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   What this second option does is let the event handler complete before you call `alert`, by scheduling a callback to `finishHandling` to occur almost immediately, but after the event handling has been completed. (I also removed the call to `event.preventDefault()`, because `return false;` from a jQuery event handler does both `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`. You may have needed it when the `alert` was there, but you don't without it.)

Comment: Great, clear explanation. Thanks a bunch. I will look into your first suggestion for not using alert().